# MVCSiteMapProvider - node.MatchesRoute

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

So I have a web app with a bunch of routes defined. The default root is as follows :

```
routes.Add(new Route("",  new RouteValueDictionary
                                     (new
                                         {
                                             param1 = "Default",
                                             param2 = "Default",
                                             controller = "Home",
                                             action = "Index"
                                         }), 
                                         null, 
                                         new RouteValueDictionary(new { namespaces = new[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" } }),
                                        myRouteHandler));
```

So theoretically when you hit the url / the instance of myRouteHandler kicks in. This handler does some replacement based up on the user context, specifically replacing param1, param2 values in the RequestContext.RouteData.

Now, I'm trying to use the MvcSiteMapProvider to build my menu using `Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(3, 1, true);`

and I have a site map with the following xml.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode key="Default" title="Default" controller="RootNode" action="None" isDynamic="false">
    <mvcSiteMapNode key="Home" title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index"   preservedRouteParameters="param1,param2">
```

The net result of all of the above is that the current node is not found so I receive an error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 1390:        public static ISiteMapNode GetNodeAtLevel(ISiteMapNode startingNode, int level, bool allowForwardSearch)
Line 1391:        {
Line 1392:            var startingNodeLevel = startingNode.GetNodeLevel();
Line 1393:            if (startingNodeLevel == level)
Line 1394:            {

Source File: c:\OpenSource\MvcSiteMapProvider\src\MvcSiteMapProvider\MvcSiteMapProvider\Web\Html\MenuHelper.cs    Line: 1392
```

The cause as far as I can tell is down to node not being able to match the route against the list of routes defined in the RouteTable.

The route values collection on the SiteMapNode contains {[param1, ABC]}, {[param2, xyz]} where as the RouteTable contains param1 = Default, param2 = Default and so when it does a key and value equality check (MvcSiteMapProvider.Collections.Specialized.RouteValueDictionary line 67), it fails to find a match.

I don't know that I've explained this problem all that well, but because of the RouteHandler changing the route data the comparison between the defined routes and the route dictionary on the sitemapnode never matches.

Thoughts and help on this welcome.

Comment: Why is there a "RootNode" and then a "Home" page? Is there really a controller named "RootNodeController" with an action named "None" in your project? If so, please post it. Better yet, build a small demo with the same problem and post it @GitHub or zip it and make it available for download.

Comment: Thanks for comment, and yes there really is a RootNode and a Home page. It's legacy I guess from when the client was using MvcSiteMap.Core (MVCSiteMapProvider v1 I think), although I suspect it was their decision and not forced. In the end to handle the difference between the route table route data and the url being executed I extended one of the methods from the MvcSiteMapProvider. It accounts for the variation between the definition and values substituted at runtime based on the user context.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful with this one. BTW - it would be better to inherit RouteBase than to build your own route handler because it is designed to work with both incoming and outgoing routes, so it will both do the match and build the URL. Not to mention, you can easily register multiple RouteBase implementations for better separation of concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll bear it in mind for the future. At present I'm not in a position to refactor the routing within my clients app as I need to limit the ripple effect of any changes. Incidentally once I understood the extension points of the MVCSiteMapProvider it wasn't too difficult to substitute my own custom implementation for the defaults built in. On the whole a very easily composable and extensible library.